# HIVE JDBC Option to allow multiple queries seperated by ';'

Tags: jdbc, hive

HIVE JDBC : I want to send multiple queries seperted by delimeter ';' to execute () of hivestatement. Is there any property thats needs to be set for hive jdbc?like allowMultipleQueries= true in mysql jdbc?

Comment: That is not how you are supposed to use JDBC. You are supposed to execute statements individually. Why is that a problem for you?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383931/hiveserver2acid-operations-failing-on-orc-table-even-after-setting-hive-transac                                                          
 the link has my question.. that is problem. The properties executed individually doesn't seem to persist between session, as each call to execute initiates a new hive session though I am unsure about it

Comment: Did you try disabling auto commit first?

Comment: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions#HiveTransactions-Limitations  says all language operations are autocommit by default.. The fearture of disabling auto commit is not yet enabled